# How to render or hide theme control only for a Document

Tags: xpages

I would like to hide theme control/property for my print Document but not working any ideas ho to go about this

```
<control rendered="#{false}">
        <name>InputField.EditBox</name>
        <property mode="concat">
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>form-control</value>
        </property>
        <property mode="override" rendered="false">
            <name>showReadonlyAsDisabled</name>
            <value>#{true}</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

I have also try to put `<control target="print.xsp" override="true">` but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only accepted property for `<control ... >` is `override="true/false"`. All other properties are ignored like `rendered=` or `target=`.

The only place you can test for XPage "print.xsp" is `<property>`'s `<value>`:

```xml
<control>
    <name>InputField.EditBox</name>
    <property
        mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>#{javascript: 
            view.getPageName().equals("/print.xsp") ? "print-control" : "form-control"
        }</value>
    </property>
```

This should give you enough control over theme controls depending on XPage though.

As an alternative, you could create an own theme for printing and apply it to your print.xsp.

Comment: if i may ask is there any standard print theme for XPages controls with  bootstrap css?

Comment: I don't think so. It is always tricky to get a nice print output from browser. We create usually a pdf with FOP as you have more control over output as developer this way.

Comment: Can u give me a sample or demo or greating pdf with FOP in regard to document and not view?

Comment: To use FOP is not that easy. It takes some days/weeks. You create XSL files to describe which data you want to put where on resulting pdf pages. The data comes in XML format (DXL or own format). XSL language is challenging but very powerful once you familiar with it.